# cannot start a cloud foundry jetty app

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to start a jetty runner application on cloud foundry. The code is

https://github.com/simbo1905/ZkToDo2

which can be started locally with

```
java -Djetty.host=localhost -Djetty.port=8080 -DDATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres -jar jetty-runner-jmx.jar zktodo2.war
```

so I created a postgresql with

```
vmc create-service postgresql pgsql
```

when zipped the jar and war into a zip then try to deploy to cloud foundry it gives me an out of memory error. What gives?

```
simbo$ vmc push zktodo2 --path=cf.zip 
Detected a Standalone Application, is this correct? [Yn]: Y
1: java
2: node
3: node06
4: ruby18
5: ruby19
Select Runtime [java]: \1
Selected java
Start Command: java -Djetty.host=${VCAP_APP_HOST} -Djetty.port=${VCAP_APP_PORT} -DDATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres -jar jetty-runner-jmx.jar zktodo2.war
Application Deployed URL [None]: 
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [512M]: 1G
How many instances? [1]: 
Bind existing services to 'zktodo2'? [yN]: y
1: pgsql
Which one?: 1
Create services to bind to 'zktodo2'? [yN]: 
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: y
Manifest written to manifest.yml.
Creating Application: OK
Binding Service [pgsql]: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (0K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Staging Application 'zktodo2': OK                                               
Starting Application 'zktodo2': .
Error: Application [zktodo2] failed to start, logs information below.

====> /logs/stderr.log <====

Could not create the Java virtual machine.

====> /logs/stdout.log <====

  Error occurred during initialization of VM
  Could not reserve enough space for object heap


  Delete the application? [Yn]:
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Foundry adds the -Xmx setting for your selected memory allocation to the JAVA_OPTS env variable, which you need to include in your start command (java $JAVA_OPTS -Djetty....).  Alternatively you could include -Xmx in your start command.

Comment: Thanks Jennifer, I was trying to follow your examples. That gets me further along. Now I get a complaint about the "guessed" postgres url. I get a connection refused for the connection to the jdbc url I gave which was "-DDATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres".  I looked at the spring+postgres example document but that actually has a hsqldb database in the spring config not an actual postgresql connection.

Comment: The app is a zk framework demo which runs on openshift and heroku. Any chance you could spare some cycles to port it to cf? In return I will broadcast to the zk community.

Comment: You don't get Spring "autoreconfig" since you're deploying a standalone app. You'll need to look at the environment var VCAP_SERVICES to get the postgres connection info. For an example look at http://gho-env.cloudfoundry.com/ and check the VCAP_SERVICES var.

Comment: anyone have an example of a spring util to make the VCAP_SERVICES easily used as spring config?

Comment: The [cloudfoundry-runtime](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java/tree/master/cloudfoundry-runtime) java library provides a Spring namespace for creating a data source(<cloud:data-source>).  If that doesn't fit your needs, the library also contains methods for parsing VCAP_SERVICE info.  Here's a small [sample](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/twitter-rabbit-socks-sample/tree/master/twitter2rabbit) that uses the namespace to connect to a Rabbit service.

Answer (score 1):

I did deploy [ZkToDo2 on cloudfoundry](http://zktodo2.cloudfoundry.com/) with a jetty-runner.
Here is the start command I used:

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=. -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512M -jar jetty-runner-jmx.jar --port ${VCAP_APP_PORT} zktodo2.war
```

In order to have the DATABASE_URL match the connection parameters of the postgresql database provisioned by cloudfoundry, I had to do some small modifications to the app.

Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/simbo1905/ZkToDo2/pull/2).

Comment: Thanks Hugues, I have broken out the config to parse the cloudfoundry env variables into a separate config https://github.com/simbo1905/ZkToDo2/blob/master/cloudforge/dburl-context.xml then added a maven profile which swaps in that config and packages the necessary jar when built with "mvn -P cloudfoundry package"

Comment: I also put in Jennifer's recommended $JAVA_OPTS into the manifest.yml.